# Bundling angularjs html files .net core

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-core, .net-core

Can I bundle html files in .net core? I was able to bundle and minify JS and CSS files. but I am not sure if i could bundle html file or not.

Answer (score 0):

Of course, angularjs and .net core can be used in combination.

Here is a detailed tutorial how to `build an Angular Application with ASP.NET Core`, please refer to [this](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/dotnet/net-development/building-an-angularjs-application-with-asp-net-core/).